# How to read from text file and set the content of it as variable?

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to remember my program what numbers i wrote

my program will look like this

```
@echo off
:: Here i want to read the file Numbers.txt
:: If it find Numbers.txt goto Read numbers if not continue
cls
set /p Number1="Enter the number > "
cls
echo First number is %Number1% > Numbers.txt
echo Number saved
cls
set /p Number2="Enter the number > "
echo Second Number is %Number2% >> Numbers.txt
:: And loop trough this like 10 Times
exit


:ReadNumbers
echo Numbers are %number1%, %number2%, %number3%, %number4%, %number5%
pause
exit
```

But i don't know how to do it
And i WANT to have written this "First number is" etc. And i want to output be like this : Numbers are %number1%, %number2%, %number3%, %number4%, %number5%
without "First number is"

Thank you
-RPochyly

Comment: What should the contents of numbers.txt look like?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to output to numbers.txt like this. `echo number1=%Number1% >Numbers.txt`.  Makes it real easy to use a `FOR /F` to read it back in.

Comment: What is For /f  ???

Comment: SomethingDark you can see it in code ( First line = First number is %number1% ; Second line = Second number is %number2% ; etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a variable from a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764065/read-a-variable-from-a-text-file)

Comment: @RPochyly, you can get help for any command by typing the command name followed by a forward slash and question mark at the cmd promt. example: `for /?`

Comment: @Squashman In former Windows versions I had suggested opening the Help file `ntcmds.chm` since this is no longer present a replacement would be [Allhelp](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/allhelp.php) The beginners could open the generated file parallel in the browser while dealing with cmd and maybe an editor window.

Comment: @LotPings, I usually just use this. http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: Type `help` in a command prompt window to get a list of available commands; type `help` + _space_ + `command` or `command /?` to get the help for the respective command...